# Error in Journey Builder: Limit exceeded

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, error

I get an error in Journey Builder: Limit exceeded. 
We are using SC data. Connector is the latest version, number of active flows is one.

Any ideas what can cause this?

[image]

Comment: Is there more to the error message than that? If so, please [edit] your question to contain the full text of the error message, _verbatim_.

Comment: How many inactive flows do you have? :-)